# FFmpeg audio channel rematrix (5.1 to stereo)

Tags: audio, video, encoding, ffmpeg, h.264

I've got a (very large!) Apple ProRes 422 file with 16ch audio. To be able to use it on a less powerful computer, I'd like to convert it to a standard MP4 file (h264 video codec, stereo audio). The original file has 16 channels of audio, however, and FFmpeg gives an error when I try to convert it ('Rematrix is needed'). How do I do rematrixing of audio channels? Are there additional steps needed?

This is the FFmpeg command I used:

```
ffmpeg -y -i Capture0000.mov -vcodec libx264 -vb 2000k -pix_fmt yuv420p -coder 0 -profile:v baseline -acodec libfaac -ab 128k /tmp/out.mp4
```

This is the FFmpeg output:

```
ffmpeg version 2.2.git Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
      built on May  8 2014 14:17:45 with gcc 4.6 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
      configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/usr/local/bin --extra-libs=-ldl --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-x11grab --enable-libxvid --enable-libfaac
      libavutil      52. 81.100 / 52. 81.100
      libavcodec     55. 60.103 / 55. 60.103
      libavformat    55. 37.102 / 55. 37.102
      libavdevice    55. 13.101 / 55. 13.101
      libavfilter     4.  5.100 /  4.  5.100
      libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
      libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
      libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
    Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Capture0000.mov':
      Metadata:
        creation_time   : 2014-08-17 18:30:31
      Duration: 01:01:22.52, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 202001 kb/s
        Stream #0:0(eng): Video: prores (apch / 0x68637061), yuv422p10le, 1920x1080, 183513 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 2500 tbn, 2500 tbc (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2014-08-17 18:30:31
          handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
          encoder         : Apple ProRes 422 (HQ)
        Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (lpcm / 0x6D63706C), 48000 Hz, 16 channels, s32, 18432 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2014-08-17 18:30:31
          handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    [auto-inserted resampler 0 @ 0x3943da0] [SWR @ 0x39441a0] Rematrix is needed between 16 channels and 5.1 but there is not enough information to do it
    [auto-inserted resampler 0 @ 0x3943da0] Failed to configure output pad on auto-inserted resampler 0
    Error opening filters!
```

This is the FFprobe output:

```
ffprobe version 2.2.git Copyright (c) 2007-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on May  8 2014 14:17:45 with gcc 4.6 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/usr/local/bin --extra-libs=-ldl --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-x11grab --enable-libxvid --enable-libfaac
  libavutil      52. 81.100 / 52. 81.100
  libavcodec     55. 60.103 / 55. 60.103
  libavformat    55. 37.102 / 55. 37.102
  libavdevice    55. 13.101 / 55. 13.101
  libavfilter     4.  5.100 /  4.  5.100
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Capture0000.mov':
  Metadata:
    creation_time   : 2014-08-17 18:30:31
  Duration: 01:01:22.52, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 202001 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: prores (apch / 0x68637061), yuv422p10le, 1920x1080, 183513 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 2500 tbn, 2500 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-08-17 18:30:31
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : Apple ProRes 422 (HQ)
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (lpcm / 0x6D63706C), 48000 Hz, 16 channels, s32, 18432 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-08-17 18:30:31
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
```

Answer (score 3):

Found it! After extracting only the audio, it turned out the first two channels were stereo, and the other four empty, so I added this:

```
-af 'pan=stereo:c0=FL:c1=FR'
```

Which takes only the front left and front right channel for the stereo mix.

EDIT: newer versions of FFMpeg require the use of | instead of :, so it would be

```
stereo|c0=FL|c1=FR
```

Comment: Note this is probably a very bad way to downmix multi channel audio.  You're completely discarding all channels except for the first 2. For most 5.1 audio source, most dialogue will be on the 3rd channel, FC.  This discards that.  Instead for a 5.1 source do something like `-af "pan=stereo|FL=FC+0.30*FL+0.30*BL|FR=FC+0.30*FR+0.30*BR" `  or just use ffmpeg's built in downmix with `-ac 2`. There's a whole discussion on how to downmix 5.1 audio here: https://superuser.com/questions/852400/properly-downmix-5-1-to-stereo-using-ffmpeg

Answer (score 2):

The posted solution completely discards all audio channels except for the first 2.  For a 16 channel audio source it's unclear how to mix this manually since I don't know what each channel means, but if you just rely on ffmpeg's built in audio channel conversion it should be better than just ignoring all channels but the first two.

```
$ ffmpeg -i Capture0000.mov -c:v copy -ac 2 stereo_output.mp4
```

In the above example `-ac 2` will tell ffmpeg to downmix the audio to stereo.  It'll then choose a reasonable default audio codec for a .mp4 file.  You can of course also choose the audio encoding settings like you did in your question.